# Strpos with variable

Tags: php, strpos

I want to delete word from text if line contain this word 
for example(if line contain hello I want to delete this line from text)
I used this code

```
$ldap="ldap".$sil;
$lines=array();

foreach(file('/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default') as $line){
    if(strpos($line,$ldap)){
        echo "dfasd";
        $line = str_replace($ldap, '', $line);
        array_push($lines, $line);
    }

    array_push($lines, $line);
}

file_put_contents('/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default', $lines);
```

but this code return that it not contain this string but when I write the string directly into strpos for example

```
strpos($line,'ldap10')
```

it deleted this line 
why Strpos not working with variables?

Comment: From PHP.net: `Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.` - you have to check for FALSE and not a truthy value like you're doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
the function return the position of word if found or return false otherwise.

so you should change your code to:

```
if(strpos($line,$ldap)!== false){}
```